# jQuery Ajax call inside for loop, not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

```
<div>
    <span id="lbl" style="font-size: 20px; color: red"></span>
</div>
```

I wrote following ajax call,

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/CallMe",
            data: "{req: '" + i + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",                
            success: function (data) {
                $("#lbl").append(" " + data.d);                    
            }
        });
    }
```

Have set a breakpoint in codebehind as below -

[image]

`CallMe` method is invoked twenty times in the loop. When first call is made I press `F5`, but value is not obtained in the client, other few `F5` hits but no return value on the client.

Having allowed code behind code to execute 5 times, I `obtain 4-5 values at once` in the client..

I tried setting `cache:false` in jQuery.ajax, which didn't help..

Any suggestion would be very much helpful !!

Comment: Debuggers aren't very good at showing you what is happening in multi-threaded code. Each request from the $.ajax call would have its own thread. Maybe the thread continues when the other thread hits the debugger breakpoint. I don't know. Maybe a thread coming the the breakpoint while the debugger is stopped in another thread will break and hold for you to release the other thread. Maybe hitting 'resume' restarts multiple stopped threads. Sometimes logging/printing messages works better in multithreaded code.

Comment: Clue (perhaps): A browser usually has a limited number of open ajax calls it can issue at one time. Any beyond that small number (2-6) will be queued up to be issued when another completes.

Answer (score 0):

Even the ajax requests are sent synchronously but the responses may not come back in the order that are sent. My guess is that you want to simulate a synchronous request and response, then one way to do that is to nest the ajax calls in the `success` block.

```
$.ajax{(
    data: 'req:1',
    success: {
        $.ajax{(
            data: 'req:2',
            success: {
                data: 'req:3',
                ...
            )}
     )}
)}
```

Comment: Nesting for few calls would be fine, if calls are `as high as 20`, following this approach would not be good, right?

Comment: I have not used it, but seems like you may want to look into control flow frameworks. One of them pops out of my mind is async. https://github.com/caolan/async